# Class doesn't exist when converting file to a module

Tags: javascript

I had code that looked like the following

```
<script src="../folder/Examples/Example.class.js"></script>

Example.setup() // fired and worked!
```

Example.class.js was a regular .js file. I converted it to a module by doing export default class Example, and now the following is failing

```
<script type="module" src="../folder/Examples/Example.class.js"></script>

Example.setup() // Example is undefined
```

What else do I need to do when converting a regular .js file to a modularized version? I am using Babel to transpile my code, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Can you please post the code of the class itself? (or, the essential parts)

Comment: @lxg What is essential about it? It contains one function. It doesn't matter what I change the function to because Example is left undefined. All i'm doing is calling export default class Example for my class declaration. I can post the skeleton of it but I'm not sure how it would add more context...

Comment: Well, then please post the class. We cannot reproduce the issue if you don’t post a [fully working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (I said “essential” because it could be that your class has 3000 lines.)

Comment: @lxg But it doesn't...

Comment: Anyway, please post the content of the `Example.class.js`. Otherwise your post is pointless. If you want people to help you, you need to do your share.